# La paroles de « la lurette en colère », une chanson québecoise

Tags: québec, paroles-de-chanson

La première fois que j’ai entendu cette chanson, c'était il y a déjà une demi-année, ça doit être la centième fois que je l’écoute, mais je ne connais pas encore les paroles.  J’ai pu trouver le premier bout en ligne, mais la fin de la chanson était introuvable. Petit à petit, j’ai saisi des parties de la chanson. Je pense comprendre ceci :

> Dans le cœur de mon village, écoutez, je vous en prie,
>       Il y a une rivière qui chante, et le jour et la nuit.
>       Elle chante pour les belles qui n’ont pas de mari.
>       Elle ne chante pas pour moi, car j’en ai un joli.
>       Il est dans la Hollande, la Hollande et [?]
>       Bon Dieu, il fait temps qu’il revienne, qu’il soit toujours en vie.
>       Qui ne sait même pas que je l’aime, trop vite il y en est parti.
>
> Entends-tu Paolo, à travers des coups des fusils
>       M’entends-tu Paolo, c’est ta belle qui t’écrit.

Voici les plus grands défauts :

- Je pensais qu’on disait « il est dans la Hollande », car cela
  s’accompagne mieux avec les paroles précédentes. Si je ne les connaissais pas, je dirais plutôt qu’on entend « il lit dans la Hollande. » D’ailleurs, je n’utiliserais jamais le mot *dans*  ici. Y a-t-il une raison pour dire *dans la* au lieu de *en* ?
- Il y a un blanc à la cinquième ligne.
- Je doute de *Bon Dieu* ici. Je n’entends pas le *D*.
- La phrase « trop vite il y en est parti » est vraisemblablement fausse, mais
  aucune meilleure chose ne m’est venue à l’esprit.

Youtube regorge de plusieurs versions de la même chanson québécoise. Voici un lien vers [la meilleure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHbnDPXu7IU) pour comprendre les paroles, elle est chantée par les frères Nicolas et Fred Pèlerin. La partie fumeuse commence à *1.10* et se termine à *2.10*. Il faut encore ajouter que les phrases sont entrelacées avec le refrain et que la plupart d’elles sont chantées trois fois. J’espère que vous pouvez la comprendre sans peine.

Comment: Quelle est ta question? || Concernant tes commentaires : "Dans la Hollande"; Il est toujours très compliquer de savoir quand utiliser *en*, *dans* ou *à*. En effet, on dit "*J'habite **à** Montréal*", "*Je suis **dans** la ville*", "*J'habite **à** Québec(ville)*", "*J'habite **au** Québec(province)*", etc. La liste est longue... "*Bon dieu ici*", en ancien Québécois (jouale), il n'était pas rare de dire "*Bon 'ieu ici*" (Ne pas prononcer le "D").

Comment: @Sifu Le joual n'est pas de l'« ancient québécois ». C'est un sociolecte encore présent dans la culture québécoise.

Comment: @Kareen, Le joual peut être décrit comme la langue des Québécois, en effet. Cependant, la façon dont ceux de mon entourage et moi utilisent ce mot est plus pour parler de la langue utilisé dans les années 1960 (le langage utilisé dans [*Les Belles-Soeurs*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Belles-S%C5%93urs) par example). Bonne chance pour trouver du monde au Québec ayant encore ce langage!

Comment: Ma question porte sur les paroles, *je veux les savoir*. Ce que j’ai écrit est une tentative de déchiffrer ce que les chanteurs disent, mais il y a bien sûr des choses que j’ai mépris. Je l’ajoute pour montrer que je me suis efforcé pour comprendre la chanson, puisque cette communauté souhaite que l’on fasse de son mieux pour trouver une réponse de sa question avant qu’on la pose ici. J’ai choisi d’inclure seulement les dernières phrases, car ceci doit être une question, pas une tâche.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Dans le coeur de mon village, écoutez, je vous en prie,
>       Il y a **la** rivière qui chante, et le jour et la nuit.
>       Elle chante pour les belles qui n’ont pas de mari.
>       Elle ne chante pas pour moi, car j’en ai un joli.
>       Il est dans la Hollande, **les Hollandais l’ont pris**.
>       Bon<sup>1</sup> Dieu, **faites donc** qu’il revienne, qu’il soit toujours en vie.
>       **Il** sait même pas que je l’aime, trop vite **il est**<sup>2</sup> parti.
>
> M’entends-tu Paulo, à travers **les** coups des fusils
>       M’entends-tu Paulo, c’est ta belle qui t’écrit.

Quelques remarques :

1. Le « mon » me semble plus logique, mais on entend plutôt un « bon » tout de même. « Bon Dieu » n’a peut-être pas le même statut d’exclamation au Québec.
2. le « trop vite il est » est prononcé de manière assez particulière : le « e » final de « vite » est prononcé, et le « il » est prononcé /j/. Ça donne donc /tro.vi.tə.je.par.ti/.

Answer (score 7):

Je ne connais pas cette chanson  québécoise *La lurette en colère*, mais  en lisant

> Il est dans la Hollande

j'ai tout de suite pensé à « Auprès de ma blonde » dont le titre orignal est *Le prisonnier de Hollande*, chanson traditionnelle française très célèbre<sup>*</sup>. Et ma première impression s'est confirmée par le reste des paroles qu'Édouard vient de nous transcrire.

Voici deux couplets de *Auprès de ma blonde*:

> Elle chante pour les filles
>       Qui n'ont pas de mari
>       Elle chante pour les filles
>       Qui n'ont pas de mari
>       C'est pas pour moi qu'elle chante
>       Car j'en ai t-un joli
>
> Dites-nous donc la belle
>       Où donc est votre ami ?
>       Dites nous donc la belle
>       Où donc est votre ami ?
>       Il est dans la Hollande
>       Les Hollandais l'ont pris

Il est clair que le parolier de cette chanson québécoise s'est très largement inspiré de cette chanson additionnelle historique (1704) qui fait allusion aux conflits entre les Provinces Unis et la France sous Louis XIV (XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle).

Tout ça pour dire qu'il ne faut pas chercher trop loin pour expliquer « dans la Hollande ». C'est du parler du XVIII <sup>e</sup> siècle et ensuite ne pas oublier que la Hollande n'était qu'une partie des Provinces Unies et qu'il arrive encore de dire « dans » devant une région/province.

Historique de *Auprès de ma blonde* [sur wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aupr%C3%A8s_de_ma_blonde).
Une interprétation de la chanson sur [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRNzxh4osFg).

<sup>* Je pense qu'elle fait partie de ce qu'on qualifie de chansons enfantines (bien que ça n'en soit pas une vraiment de par le contenu) que tous les français connaissent mais je suis surprise d'être la première à en faire la remarque. Ou alors ce site n'est-il fréquenté que par des jeunes, très jeunes dont je serais une doyenne ?</sup>

Comment: Les chansons du patrimoine culturel n'ont pas d'âge, elles sont chantées tout au long d'une vie. On en connaît les premiers vers, mais ceux de la fin sont emmenés par Léthé ; doyenne ou non vous n'y avez certainement pas trempé votre lèvres pour avoir su faire ce rapprochement ! Tout le monde connaît *auprès de ma blonde*, mais parler *du prisonnier de Hollande* en cette mandature ouvre des perspectives aux chansonnettes.

Answer (score 1):

Merci pour les précisions, effectivement "auprès de ma blonde" est une comptine, comme beaucoup d'airs traditionnels elle est passée dans le registre "enfantin" malgré un contenu plutôt violent.
Il y a de nombreux autres cas : "Malbrough s'en va-t-en guerre", par exemple, "Jean Petit qui danse" ou "Au clair de la Lune" en sont parmi les plus connues.
La chanson qui nous intéresse ici est également connue sous le titre "Le pont de Lyon", qui est dans l'Anthologie de la Chanson Française par Marc Orgeret mais c'est également une très jolie mazurka enregistrée par le groupe Estrad

http://trad95.free.fr/gif/LepontdeLyon.pdf